# Regular expression to get a match or replace a subString

Tags: java, regex

I need to match or replace a part of string like below, but I couldn't write the exact regular expression for that in java.

String:

```
text1${text2${text3}text4}text5
```

Expected regex should match the test3 alone, ie. anything inside "inner" ${}. Above example has an outer ${...} and an inner ${...}, like ...${...${...}...}.... And test3 is inside the "inner ${} which is what I want.

The following regex captures the entire content within ${...}, not just the content of "inner" ${...}

```
\$\{(.*?)\}
```

More Examples:

```
text1${text2${text3}text4}text5 - match "text3"
text1text2${text3}text4text5    - should not match anything
text1${text2${text3}text4text5  - should not match anything
```

Update:

```
text1${text2${text3}${text4}text5} - match "text3" and "text4"
```

Comment: Give several examples of input, and for each input, show the desired output for that input.

Comment: @DavidChoweller added few examples

Comment: @user3366706 take a look for you update that I have written

Answer (score 2):

The `.` matches both `{` and `}`. You need to exclude matching `{` and `}`:

```
\$\{([^{}]*)}
     ^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nfkA4r/2). The `[^{}]*` is a [negated character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) matching 0+ chars other than `{` and `}`.

[Java code](http://ideone.com/C3OWyl):

```
String str = "text1${text2${text3}text4}text5";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\$\\{([^{}]*)}");
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
// => text3
```

Comment: this one matches even with single ${...} like if string is "text1${text2}text3" then text2 matches your regex. but it would be nice if I can get only that matches "inner" ${}, so "text1${text2}text3" should not have anything matching, but string like this "text1${text2${text3}}" should match the inner text3 substring

Comment: Try [`"\\$\\{[^{}]*\\$\\{([^{}]*)}[^{}]*}"`](https://regex101.com/r/gMeaU9/1) regex.

Answer (score 0):

**First** you need to match the entire between the first `{` and the last `}` and after that you can match **what you want** by using **match-group**.

**what you want**
`{.*\{(.*?)\}.*?\}`

In the first step it match `{text2${text3}` and after that you should use math-group

I am not familiar with **Java** but I know a little with **Perl** and **C++** and I think it works in **Java** because it is easy and not complex

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/cxWiRS/1)

---

**Test with Perl**

`echo 'text1${text2${text3}text4}text5' | perl -lne '/\{.*\{(.*?)\}.*?\}/ && print $1'`

**output**

`text3`

---

So in you **Java** code use `$1` that's it.

---

For your update that you wrote, you have 2 choices **one** with a `loop` over your string and **other** with four `match-group`

**First with a while loop**
`echo 'text1${text2${text3}${text4}text5}' | perl -lne 'print $2 while /(\${)(\w+)(\$?})/g'`
`text3`
`text4`
How does it work? very easy. It first match `${text3}` and here `\w+` would be *text3* then it goes ahead and match `${text4}` and again `\w+` would be *text4*
`(\${)(\w+)(\$?})`
[prove](https://regex101.com/r/vHIEXf/1)

**Second with non-loop**
`echo 'your-string' | perl -lne ' /(\${)(\w+)(\$?})\1(\w+)\3/g && print $2," ",$4'`

This one also easy. It first matches *text3* and then matches *text4* and puts them in `$2` and `$4`. that's it.
`(\${)(\w+)(\$?})\1(\w+)\3`
[prove](https://regex101.com/r/wesDfE/1)

**NOTE**
With while loop you need to use **g flag** and you can not ignore it but for second no problem.
Again

Comment: with slight modification it works for what I wanted \${.*\$\{(.*?)\}.*?\} There is a slight improvement I need from this regex. For example: in this string text1${text2${that}text4${this}text5} it captures only 'this', ie. only one inner substring. I could not make it to capture all matching substring in one go, ie. capture 'this', and 'that' in one go.

Comment: @user3366706 your ask does not make sense to me. You should know that **regexes** are very sensitive and I wrote this for your purpose that you wrote above. If you want a thing for both or anything just **update** your question. Also this `text1${text2${that}text4${this}text5}` is difference from one you have written. So think and exactly tell what you want.